# Unexpected token in React Component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-component

I'm trying to include a Bootstrap component to my 'ContactList' component but it isn't accepting anything within the return{} para. What am I doing wrong?

I have added the necessary JS and CSS dependencies for Bootstrap.

[image]

Comment: use `className`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can you provide a pen or fiddle for your question

Comment: @FareedKhan I did that and still doesn't work.

Comment: @Dlucidone what does that mean?

Comment: The problem was that I was using flower braces instead of curly braces.

Comment: can you provide sample code in online editor where we can look for problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
return (
  <div className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't make a difference!

Comment: @ArjunRam change it on all screens ```class``` is a reserved word can't be used to assign classes to tag

Comment: @ArjunRam  
Please add

 import React from 'react'